# sum() function to sum all items in a given list

Tags: python, list, function, sum, pythomnic3k

there is a function I want to define that takes all items in a list and adds them up together:

```
def sum():

for x in range(len(user)):
    sum = 0
    sum =+ user[x]
    return sum

user = [1,1,1]
score = sum()
print(score)
```

for some reason it prints just 1, and my wanted output is 3.

Comment: Fix the indentation of the shown code (if you do it right, it will also solve your problem).

Comment: Why would you want to obliterate the *sum()* built-in function?

Comment: And please not re-define the built-in `sum` as it'll shadow some future use.

Comment: You're resetting sum to 0 on _each_ loop iteration.  Don't do that.  Move `sum = 0` to be above the loop.  Also you have a `return` inside the loop, which will exit the function immediately.  Move the `return` to be after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a list of integers you could do this:

```
my_list = [1, 1, 1]

def accumulation(list_):
  total = 0
  for i in list_:
    total += i
  return total
```

...or...

```
sum(my_list) # where sum is the Python built-in function
```

Answer (score 0):

You re-define `sum` for each `x` which means that your `sum` is always `user[x]`. Additionally, you return immediately after the first `x` element.

A possible solution is this:

```py
def sum(user):
    sum = 0
    for u in user:
        sum += u
    return sum

print(sum([1,1,1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to ident your for loop:

```
def sum():

for x in range(len(user)):
    sum = 0
    sum =+ user[x]
    return sum

user = [1,1,1]
score = sum()
print(score)
```

should be...

```
def sum():

    for x in range(len(user)):
        sum = 0
        sum =+ user[x]
    return sum

user = [1,1,1]
score = sum()
print(score)
```

...to achieve your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers work. Bu I was thinking, why not use `sum(list)` ? It would return the same output as expected but a lot less code.